# Possible to apply this specific "look" to a matplotlib bar chart?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm looking for tips on getting my data from a pandas dataframe into a matplotlib chart that looks this:
[image: formatted chart example]

Is it even possible without too much effort?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Is your question solved now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folllowing functionality can be used:

- Generate a standard bar plot using pandas' `df.plot.bar()`
- Loop through the generated bars to change their color and alpha. Also use the bar's dimensions to place a text with the height.
- Remove all spines except the bottom spine.
- Change the linewidth of the bottom spine.
- Use `grid()` to place horizontal grid lines.
- Use `tick_params()` to remove the tick marks and change tick label color and size. The y-ticks can not be removed as they are needed to position the grid lines.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [40, 55, 60, 94, 79, 49]},
                  index=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June'])
colors = plt.cm.tab10.colors[:len(df)]
ax = df.plot.bar(width=0.9, legend=False)
for p, color in zip(ax.patches, colors):
    p.set_color(color)
    p.set_alpha(0.6)
    ax.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_y() + p.get_height() / 2, f'{p.get_height():.0f}', ha='center',
            va='center', fontsize=20)
ax.grid(axis='y')
for where in ['left', 'right', 'top']:
    ax.spines[where].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(3)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', length=0, labelcolor='none')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0, rotation=0, labelsize=14)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: If you need the more grey-like colors, you could first make them darker:

```
colors = [(r*0.6, g*0.6, b*0.6) for r, g, b in colors]
```

And still use the alpha (`0.5`?) to make them whiter again.

[image: grayer plot]

Answer (score 1):

After initializing your data frame, you could get bar chart `df.plot.bar` or `df.plot(kind='bar')`.

For each column, you can set the color, either with hexadecimal value or color name.

Finally, to label on the bar chart, you need to get the dimension of the graph.

Below is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

data = {'T1-Hotshots': [40],
        'Type_2_IA': [55],
        'Engines': [60],
        'Helicopters': [94],
        'Dozers': [79],
        'Patrols': [49]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['T1-Hotshots',
                                 'Type_2_IA',
                                 'Engines',
                                 'Helicopters',
                                 'Dozers',
                                 'Patrols'])

x_pos = [i for i, _ in enumerate(data)]

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', color=['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange',
                                'purple', 'red'])
rects = ax.patches

labels = [df[key].values[0] for key in df]

for rect, label in zip(ax.patches, labels):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height - 25, label,
            ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]